# Firebase different errors on instances of same project

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I've created my original app 2 years ago, and today created a new instance of the same app. How come that a when user tries to sign in with an invalid email in the new app I get an error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

yet in the old one I get

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Why isn't it the same error in both cases?

Comment: In the new version of firebase app, they may changed authentication message is more generic without specifying the particular invalid user input. see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors